# php, html generate form from mutiple variables

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to generate a html form with different hidden variables . However the "problem" is that there are a lot of variables .e.g

```
   $siteId = getValue("siteId", $localurl);
   $itemid = getValue("itemid", $localurl);
   $bidqty = getValue("bidqty", $localurl);
   $maxbid = getValue("maxbid", $localurl);
   $lagoonemorebid = getValue("lagoonemorebid", $localurl);
```

$tokenstring  = getValue("tokenstring", $localurl);
   $usage  = getValue("usage", $localurl);
   $robotimage = getValue("robotimage", $localurl);
   $ru = getValue("ru", $localurl);
   $usergoal = getValue("usergoal", $localurl);
   $reporting = getValue("reporting", $localurl);
   $buyerLogging = getValue("buyerLogging", $localurl);
   $runame = getValue("runame", $localurl);
   $ruparams = getValue("ruparams", $localurl);
   $PromoCode = getValue("PromoCode", $localurl);

... the above vars are just a few from the whole list . Basically I can generate the form manually with

```
  echo "
form action=\"http://$domain/mailer/create.php\" name=\"create\" method=\"post\" />
input type=\"hidden\" name=\"random\" value=\"$random\" />
```

but I was wondering if there is a "smart" technique to use foreach or some function to get all the variables and generate the form instead to write manually all the hidden inputs ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume getValue is a custom function. My recommendation would be the following:

```
 <?php
 // arrays to facilitate foreach loop
 $hidden_fields = array('siteId', 'itemid', 'bidqty'); // store hidden field names
 $hidden_values = array(); // store the hidden field values

 foreach ($hidden_fields as $key => $value) {
  // fill the values array using the values from fields array
  $hidden_values[$value] =  getValue($value, $localurl);
 }


 <?php
 echo "
 form action=\"http://$domain/mailer/create.php\" name=\"create\" method=\"post\" />
 input type=\"hidden\" name=\"random\" value=\"$random\" />";

 // output hidden fields
 foreach ($hidden_values as $key => $value) {
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="', $key, '" value="', $value, '" />';
 }
 ?>
```

You could do this with a single array, but I feel this is more flexible.

Comment: This exposes XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way. Add all your values into an array and use the PHP function **array_walk**.

eg:

```
$hiddenVars = array(
   'siteId' => getValue("siteId", $localurl),
   'itemid' => getValue("itemid", $localurl),
   .....
);

function outputHiddenFields(&$val, $key) {
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="', $key, '" value="', $val, '" />';
}

array_walk( $hiddenVars, 'outputHiddenFields' );
```

The advantage of this method is that your array $hiddenVars could change dynamically and this would still work.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a smarter way. You can use just one hidden field and the value would be encoded serialized string of all of your variables :

```
$options = array(
'asd' => 1,
'zxc' => 2,
);
$options = base64_encode(serialize($options));
echo '<input type="hidden" name="state" value="' . $options . '" />';
```

Then you can get values like this:

```
$options = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['state']));
```